# Construct polynomial-time algorithm to decide whether there is a linear classifier containing all points in X and no points in Y

Tags: automata, np

Consider n-dimensional linear classifiers, that is, subsets of R n that have the form {(x1, x2, . . . , xn)| a1x1 + a2x2 + · · · + anxn ≥ b} for some real numbers a1, . . . , an and b. Given as input two sets X and Y of polynomiallymany points in R n , show that there is a polynomial-time algorithm to decide whether there is a linear classifier containing all points in X and no points in Y . (Hint: You can assume that Linear Feasibility, that is, the problem of deciding whether a given set of linear inequalities in n real variables has a solution or not, is in the class P.)

I know that since the number of points in sets X and Y are polynomially bounded, the number of inequalities we construct is also polynomially bounded. Thus, the algorithm will run in polynomial time. But I still dont really know how to approach the step-by step process,especially how to construct the linear inequalities